# Get current directory through alias in git-bash (windows)

Tags: shell, git-bash

This command prints the directory name just fine:

```
echo ${PWD##*/}
```

This alias in .bashrc does not:

```
alias echodir="echo ${PWD##*/}"
```

They both work fine in the home directory, but after changing directories only typing it in manually works. The alias still prints the home folder. I understand this is because git bash works with nested shells or something - the base shell doesn't change directories at all, but the surface one does.

Is there a way to create an alias that works as expected?

Comment: Try single quotes instead of double quotes - single quotes prevent expansion of variable references.

Comment: That worked! Thanks! I used double quotes because the full echo had other text in it, but using the info you shared I was able to get it to work:

`alias updating='echo "-----Updating "${PWD##*/}"-----"'`

Comment: @twalberg you should post that as the official answer so I can accept it! Otherwise I'll add it myself eventually, but you should get the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just posting the answer twalberg put in the comments(he gets the credit):

As a one-off command:

`echo "-----Updating "${PWD##*/}"-----"`

As an alias:

`alias updating='echo "-----Updating "${PWD##*/}"-----"'`